# Parameter passed into Swift closure not being used

Tags: swift, xcode

I can’t understand why Pizza is returned instead of Tomato here, even when calling for Tomato:

```
var foodArray = ["Pizza", "Tomato"]
var food = {
    (name: String) -> String in
    for item in foodArray {
        if item == "Pizza" {
            return "eating \(foodArray[0]) everyday could be bad for your health."
        } else if item == "Tomato" {
            return "\(foodArray[1]) is good for your health."
        }
    }
    return "the food you entered is not valid."
}

food("Tomato")
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, post text. The parameter `name` is unused in the code and the first item in the array is Pizza.

Comment: got it! I never used this site before so, I didn't know about that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through `foodArray` and the first item is "Pizza" so it will always return the statement about pizza. You do not make use of the string that is passed into the closure, which is called "name." Remove the for loop and replace:

```
if item == "Pizza"
...
else if item == "Tomato"
```

with:

```
if name == "Pizza"
...
else if name == "Tomato"
```

Comment: thank you! I just did that before seeing your answer! sorry for wasting your time!